# $\left|\int^{T \theta}_0 \frac{\sin x}{x} dx\right|$ is bounded above by $\sup_y \int^y_0 \frac{\sin x}{x}dx$

Tags: probability, integration, measure-theory

Basically, we need to prove $\left|\int^{T \theta}_0 \frac{\sin x}{x} dx\right|$ is bounded above by $\sup_y \int^y_0 \frac{\sin x}{x}dx < \infty$. This to utilize the dominated convergence theorem as $T \rightarrow \infty$. Hence, we may think of $\theta$ as a constant here.

Here are the relevant section from my textbook.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The integral $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is not absolutely convergent on $(0,\infty)$, so I see no reason why we must have $\left|R(\theta,T) \right| \leq 2 \sup_y S(y)$ here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this follows from that $\text{Si}(t) = \int_0^t\frac{\sin x}{x}dx$ is always positive for $t > 0$, even though I do not know why $\text{Si}(t)$ is always positive for $t > 0$.

Comment: $Si(t)>0$ is obvious since you can write it for $t > \pi$ as the integrand is clearly positive for $t <\pi$) as $\int_0^{\pi}\sin x (1/x-1/(x+\pi)+1/(x+2\pi)-1/(x+3\pi)+..-1/(x+(2k-1)\pi)dx + \int_{2\pi k}^t \sin x/x$ where $k=[t/2\pi]$ and the first integral is clearly positive, while the last is also clearly positive